# How to make a wavy filter for animation

Tags: animation

I have a simple animation, i want the animation to have a riple effect like in after effect when it makes the animation looks wavy (Like looking things underwater from above). Is this possible to achive by blender? Can someone suggest me the way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Create a plane, give it a glass material (*Transmission* at 1 and *Roughness* at O, subdivide it, give it a *Displace* modifier with a *Clouds* texture, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, create an empty that will be the *Displace* object:

[image]

Keyframe the empty:

[image]